# No module named sklearn.model_selection in jupyter notebook

Tags: scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

**I have installed the sklearn package in the environment**
[image]
**and I can succeed to import sklearn in the terminate.**
[image]
**But when I run the project of boston_housing.ipynb, I got an ImportError: No module named sklearn.model_selection**
[image]
**How can I fix this problem?**

Comment: Why your package list seems to be for Python 3.6 (`py36`), while you are running Python 2.7? Do these lists come from your `py2` virtual environment? Try a `pip list` *after* activating the environment, and see if `sklearn` is included in the `py2` environment available packages...

Answer (score 5):

As rightfully stated by desertnaut, you're using Python 2 but the `conda list` command shows packages installed for Python 3. After you `source activate py2` run the `conda list` command again and check for scikit-learn. If it's not listed you can simply install it with `conda install scikit-learn`. In every conda environment, you have to install packages seperately.

Comment: I have the same problem as OP, and for me `scikit-learn` is listed there, with version `0.19.1`

Comment: What does it say after the 0.19.1? Are you using Python 2 or 3 in your jupyter notebook?

Comment: I actually found the problem! I had the right version when I was checking in terminal, but I was not using the right kernel in Jupyter Notebook. I had to write a command to add my conda environment as a kernel in Jupyter, and from there I was using 0.19.1 instead of the `17` version.